# Managing subscriptions based on async event

Tags: asynchronous, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

Im looking a way to simplify this and avoid managing subscriptions inside my pipe.

The general idea abought my code:

```js
this.start$ubject // waiting for users call to start
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => from(this.thirdPartyService.start())), // now i need to wait for smth to start
    tap(() => {
      // only after thirdPartyService started i can subscribe because prior to that they are undefined
      this.subscriptions.push(
        this.thirdPartyService.alfa$.subscribe(this.first$ubject),
        this.thirdPartyService.beta$.subscribe(this.second$ubject),
      );
    }),
  );
```

Is there any way to deal with that? Something like `takeWhile` but for subscription?

Comment: I have some questions: how many times start$ubject will emit a value? When it is emitting multiple times before `this.thirdPartyService.start()`, `alfa$` and `beta$` is completing it will run the `thirdPartyService` multiple times. So first of all, is this what you want. 

There is a way the manage your subscriptions. You can use instead of a tab the zip operator.

Comment: It is necessary to push your subscriptions into this.subscriptions? Sorry for all these questions. It is also important that you solve your problem correctly.

Comment: @SerkanSipahi the start$ubject will emit multiple times and every time i need to start that service and recieve unique `alfa$` and `beta$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like that:

```js
// waits for start$ubject, then waits for thirdPartyService, then starts.
this.subscriptions.push(
  this.start$ubject.pipe(
    switchMap(() => from(this.thirdPartyService.start())), // waiting start
    switchMap(() => merge( // listening on both of the streams
      this.thirdPartyService.alfa$.pipe(
        tap(this.first$ubject),
      ),
      this.thirdPartyService.beta$.pipe(
        tap(this.second$ubject),
      ),
    )),
  ).subscribe(),
);
```

```js
// waits for start$ubject or for thirdPartyService, then starts.
this.subscriptions.push(
  merge(this.start$ubject, from(this.thirdPartyService.start()).pipe(
    switchMap(() => merge( // listening on both of the streams
      this.thirdPartyService.alfa$.pipe(
        tap(this.first$ubject),
      ),
      this.thirdPartyService.beta$.pipe(
        tap(this.second$ubject),
      ),
    )),
  ).subscribe(),
);
```

Comment: I cant use `merge` because it will merge my observables and i need to act differently on `alpha$` and `beta$` emits.

Comment: Why? this stream has an empty subscribe that ignores emits. If you want to act on `alpha$` and `beta$` simply use `tap`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And when user need to restart this service again by emitting into start$ubject? Should i use switchMap instead of exhaustMap?

Comment: yes. but you need to change sequence, currently it waits `this.start$ubject`, then it waits `this.thirdPartyService.start()`, then it starts the sequence. If you want to restart it with every emit of `this.start$ubject` and `this.thirdPartyService.start()` - then use switchMap, if any of these two can trigger start then use merge there. I'll update the answer

Comment: switchMap will wait for `thirdPartyService` to start before it proceeds? i thought i need `mergeMap` for that

Comment: both of them wait. The question is what you want to do once it emits. Because with switchMap it unsubscribes from old stream with merge map it creates 2nd stream so every emit will cause alpha beta to be triggered as many times at mergeMap was called.